# Finding Perfect numbers which are sum of consecutive prime number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, perfect-numbers

Find all Perfect numbers which are sum of consecutive prime number.
For ex . we can write $28$ as :
$$28 = 2+3+5+7+11$$

Are there any more examples possible ? If yes , what is the general condition to find such numbers ?

Comment: Do you know the general form of (even) perfect numbers?

Comment: $\frac {q(q+1)} {2} $ , where q is a prime of the form $2^p -1 $ and p is a prime.

Comment: Odd perfect numbers probably do not exist and the even ones are completely classified with the Mersenne primes : If $N$ is an even perfect number, then there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $$N=2^k\cdot (2^{k+1}-1)$$ where $2^{k+1}-1$ is a (Mersenne)-prime. Did you check $496$ and $8128$ ?

Comment: One part of the question is done (another solution). To find systematically representations for larger perfect numbers (if existent) could be difficult.

Comment: [Perfect numbers](https://oeis.org/A000396/b000396.txt) get very big really fast. Nothing special is known about [representing numbers as sums of consecutive primes](https://oeis.org/A084143) afaik. I do not think we can do any better than find just few small examples.

Answer (score 4):

$496$ has a representation : $$5+7+11+\cdots +53+59+61=496$$ For $8128$ and $33550336$ , there is no such representation. Hard to say what is the case for larger perfect numbers.

Comment: What is special about 28 and 496?

Comment: To find the perfect numbers is no problem, but to check whether there is such a representation is time consuming. I guess it is unlikely to find representations for larger perfect numbers because the probability to hit the number just gets too small, but I am not sure. According to my calculations, the next perfect number ($33550336$) has no representation either.

Comment: I think what is special about $28$ and $496$ is that they are small, and there are lots of small primes. $8128$ and the rest are big, and there aren't so many big primes.

Comment: and if the number doesn't use 2, it always takes an even number of odd primes to add to it if it even exists.

Answer (score 3):

Some further calculations to add to [Peter's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3384099/420432):

$8589869056$ is the sum of the $1390$ consecutive primes from $6168691$ to $6190871$.

$137438691328$ is the sum of the $112240$ consecutive primes from $454969$ to $2019869$.

$2305843008139952128$ is the sum of the $26$ primes from $88686269543843669$ to $88686269543844787$.

Despite these positive results, there's no obvious pattern and so there's insufficient evidence to say whether perfect numbers are any more or less likely to be sums of consecutive primes than any other positive integers.